# Validate TextBox for specific string

Tags: c#, .net, validation, textbox

I have a textbox that will end up being the body of an email. The problem I am having is some people are placing links within this textbox and when the email goes out there are a bunch of hyperlinks in the body. I want to prevent that from happening by validating the textbox so when it see's text containing "http://" in the textbox to prompt the user to remove any links inside the textbox before they can continue.

I need IsBodyHtml = true to be set because I have an image that automatically gets inserted in the body as well. So disabling isn't an option for me at the moment.

```
<strong>Alert Description</strong><br>
<asp:TextBox ID="AlertDesTxtBox" Rows="15" Width="450" TextMode="MultiLine"
             runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RFV3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="AlertDesTxtBox"
             ErrorMessage="Description is required."
             ForeColor="Red">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Any suggestions? CustomValidator?

Comment: Have you looked at using regex yet?

Comment: Agree with @AMR, this seems like a problem regular expressions were invented to solve.

Comment: @AMR I will check this out now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction I wasn't aware of regular expressions!

Comment: @kcray that's what the community is here for! If you need a good resource I am pretty sure http://www.Pluralsight.com has a very nice list of videos on how to use regexs. They are pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily search for "http://":

```
int startIndex = 0, remaining = textBox.Text.Length;

while ((startIndex = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(startIndex, textBox.Text.Length - startIndex)) > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is a link in here");
    startIndex++;
}
```